# Is [NSMutableIndexSet copy] behavior incorrect?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableset

Look at following two statements:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *selectedRows = [[[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexSet:[_dataTableView selectedRowIndexes]] autorelease];
NSMutableIndexSet *rowsToDelete = [[selectedRows copy] autorelease];
```

I expected rowsToDelete to be an NSMutableIndexSet, but its NSIndexSet. Looks like copy is not implemented in NSMutableIndexSet.
If thats so, isn't it a big miss not implementing copy even for such a basic type? or I am missing something fundamental to IndexSet interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, the behavior is correct.

You are probably confused by the difference between `copy` and `mutableCopy`.

`copy` returns the object returned by `copyWithZone:`. That in turn will return an immutable variant if the class has both an immutable and an mutable variant.

See the **discussion** in [the documentation for `copyWithZone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCopying/copyWithZone%3a):

> The copy returned is immutable if the consideration “immutable vs. mutable” applies to the receiving object; otherwise the exact nature of the copy is determined by the class.

Comment: I didn't get it. Both the receiving object and source are NSMutableIndexSet here.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Its the same problem I was facing

Comment: @NiteshChordiya The copy method doesn't know anything about how it's being received. If you want a mutable copy then you should use `mutableCopy`.

Answer (score 1):

Copy returns a non mutable copy. If you want to obtain a mutable copy, you have to send the message "mutableCopy" to a class that implements the NSMutableCopying protocol.
As you can see in the developer documentation, NSMutableIndexSet conforms to both NSMutableCopying and NSCopying protocols:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html